# Hide sheets in shared excel workbook.

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I have a shared workbook on which I have hidden some of the worksheets prior to saving.
I have closed the workbook. If another user opens the workbook the worksheets I had hidden are visible. If I open the workbook (in shared mode), the worksheets are still hidden. is there any way to hide them so know one can see them but they can still be accessible if we need to view at them later?

Comment: check out https://superuser.com/a/1254449/774984 for more info

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Right-click on the tab you'd like to hide.
- Choose "View Code"
- Under "Visible" change the value to (2) "VeryHidden"

If you care to password protect it from there continue...

- In the VBA window, right-click the sheet and choose "VBAProject Properties"
- Under the Protection tab, check "Lock Project for Viewing"
- Set password

I'm almost certain that this will accomplish what you need without having to save the workbook as a macro-enabled workbook, xls(x) will work.