# How to unhide 'Very Hidden' Worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel

I was messing around in the sheet settings and somehow managed to make a sheet 'very hidden', but I cannot seem to make it visible again. How can I make it visible?

I am using Excel 2010.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One option is to do it with VBA

Try out the below:

```vb
Sub UnHide()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Visible = True
Next
End Sub
```

This will show up **ALL** sheets that are hidden, or very hidden

Comment: Yeah, `Very Hidden` can only be unhidden with VBA.

Comment: No, that's wrong. See my reply.

Comment: @NiklasJ The code is not wrong; this will work to set them to visible.

Comment: @NiklasJ - this code will unhide all sheets in one go, your method will unhide one sheet at a time. Neither is wrong, both are correct. This is the method I would have chosen because I didn't even know your method existed! TIL!

Comment: @TylerH I think Nilklas was referring to the implicit statement that you must use code to unhide the cells. His answer does not rely on code.

Comment: i didn't say you HAD to use code, i just didn't think the settings were available, I have edited it now anyways

Comment: And my reply lacked a @BruceWayne reference which might have cleared things up... =)

Comment: @NiklasJ ah, yeah. I should have said VBA/VBE. (But to be honest I forgot you could do it in the editor without using code. Good call!)

Answer (score 60):

You do it like this:

1. Open VBA editor (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F11</kbd>)
2. Open the VBAProject corresponding to your file.
3. Open the "Microsoft Excel-objects" folder
4. Select the Sheet you've hidden.
5. Go to the properties (press <kbd>F4</kbd>)
6. Change the property "Visible" to xlSheetVisible instead of xlSheetVeryHidden

Answer (score 15):

In VBA editor, go to the sheet properties and change the below property

[image]

Comment: this is the same method as NiklasJ above ?

Comment: I just noticed, yes it is the same but with picture.

Comment: You should have edited @NiklasJ's answer and added the picture...

Comment: I accidentally hid the only sheet in a workbook!  I tried  the above, saved the spreadsheet, and tried to open it, and it (entire workbook) is not visible.  Any ideas?

Comment: *Ha!  I had another spreadsheet open, and that is why I couldn't see anything.  I closed all Excel workbooks, then opened it, nothing was visible but the "View" toolbar had an unhide option enabled!*

Answer (score 1):

To keep them hidden, but visible in the options menu (UnHide..), use the same code but with this..

```
Sub StillHide()
Dim ws As Worksheet
For Each ws In Sheets
    ws.Visible = xlSheetHidden  <-- change from Visible to this.
Next
End Sub
```

That way the tabs are not all of a suddenly showing to the user. They are still "hidden".