# What does ' '!$A$1 means in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-office

While looking for a dynamic tournament-schedule in Excel, I stumbled upon this formula:

```
=IF(' '!$A$1=0;D7;  ...)
```

Usually, I use the "!"-Operator when referring to another worksheet.

What does it mean in this context?

Comment: it means the sheet name is a space.

Comment: but a sheet with a space as its name does not exist. shouldn't this result in an error?

Comment: @ErikWeber if the formula returns a #REF error, then there isn't a sheet named with a space, if you do NOT see this error, then there is a sheet indeed named with a space, try looking in hidden sheets and very hidden sheets

Comment: see one of my old answers on how to unhide a very hidden work sheet https://superuser.com/questions/1254447/how-to-unhide-very-hidden-worksheet/1254449#1254449

Comment: thank you so much @PeterH! there was in fact a very hidden sheet, I didn't even know that existed to be honest. good to know tho.

Comment: No probs welcome to SuperUser

Comment: @PeterH,, please post your findings on the issue as an answer,, it's tricky one help many ☺

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unhide 'Very Hidden' Worksheet](https://superuser.com/questions/1254447/how-to-unhide-very-hidden-worksheet)